# How to use kernel header <linux/gfp.h>

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Hi i am developing a small program that allocates physical pages dynamically using **Alloc_pages** function declared in gfp.h but when i am trying to compile it encounters an error with message **linux/gfp.h** no such file or directory. How can i use this header to develop memory management programs. Any suggestions are heartly welcomed.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I suggest you look at the manual for your compiler and find the section about specifying include paths.

Answer (score 1):

> Hi i am developing a small program that allocates physical pages dynamically using Alloc_pages function declared in gfp.h…

That won't work.

The `linux/gfp.h` header file declares functions that are available *within the kernel*. These functions cannot be called directly by userspace applications; the header file can only be used for building kernel modules.

Answer (score 0):

Its may be due to your linux headers not installed.
try this:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-3.19.0-79-generic
```

This command is for linux headers 3.19.0.79 generic , do this according to your kernel version.